# Uploading ProGuard Mapping Files to Firebase for many flavors and build types

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I've multiple flavors and build types so I have multiple firebaseUpload tasks:

```
firebaseUploadFlavor1BetaProguardMapping
firebaseUploadFlavor1StagingProguardMapping
firebaseUploadFlavor1ReleaseProguardMapping

firebaseUploadFlavor2BetaProguardMapping
firebaseUploadFlavor2StagingProguardMapping
firebaseUploadFlavor2ReleaseProguardMapping
```

Unfortunately, there is no firebaseUploadBetaProguardMapping or similar task. Is it possible to create my own task which will upload all proguard files for all flavors and build types automatically?

Answer (score 2):

I've resolved this issue using by adding this code to my app's build.gradle file:

```
task uploadProguardMappings {
    println "Uploading Firebase Proguard Mapping Files"
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

    def flavor = variant.flavorName.capitalize()
    def buildType = variant.getBuildType().name.capitalize()

    if(!buildType.equals("Debug")) {
        println "firebaseUpload" + flavor + buildType + "ProguardMapping"
        uploadProguardMappings.dependsOn "firebaseUpload" + flavor + buildType + "ProguardMapping"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Radzio, Could you please explain how the actual uploading of mapping.xml was done. I am also facing same issue where I need to upload mapping file to multiple firebase application.